# How to mimic Optaplanner 7's MoveIteratorFactoryToMoveSelectorBridge in Optaplanner 8

Tags: kotlin, optaplanner

We have implemented a custom construction heuristic with Optaplanner 7. We didn't use a simple `CustomPhaseCommand`; Instead, we extend `MoveSelectorConfig` and override `buildBaseMoveSelector` to return our own MoveFactory wrapped in a  `MoveIteratorFactoryToMoveSelectorBridge`. We decided to do so, because it gives us the following advantages:

- global termination config is supported out of the box
- type safe configuration from code (no raw Strings)

With Optaplanner 8 the method `buildBaseMoveSelector` is gone from the `MoveSelectorConfig` API and building a custom config class seems to be prevented in the new implementation of [MoveSelectorFactory](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/8.0.x/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/heuristic/selector/move/MoveSelectorFactory.java#L50).

Is it still possible to inject a proper custom construction heuristic into the Optaplanner 8 configuration and if yes, how? Or should we be using a `CustomPhaseCommand` with a custom self-implemented termination?

**EDIT:**

For clarity, in Optaplanner 7 we had the following snippet in our Optaplanner-config (defined in kotlin code):

```
        ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig().apply {
            foragerConfig = ConstructionHeuristicForagerConfig().apply {
                pickEarlyType = FIRST_FEASIBLE_SCORE
            }
            entityPlacerConfig = QueuedEntityPlacerConfig().apply {
                moveSelectorConfigList = listOf(
                    CustomMoveSelectorConfig().apply {
                        someProperty = 1
                        otherProperty = 0
                    }
                )
            }
        },
```

`CustomMoveSelectorConfig` extends `MoveSelectorConfig` and overrides `buildBaseMoveSelector`:

```
class CustomMoveSelectorConfig(
    var someProperty: Int = 0,
    var otherProperty: Int = 0,
) : MoveSelectorConfig<CustomMoveSelectorConfig>() {

    override fun buildBaseMoveSelector(
        configPolicy: HeuristicConfigPolicy?,
        minimumCacheType: SelectionCacheType?,
        randomSelection: Boolean,
    ): MoveSelector {
        return MoveIteratorFactoryToMoveSelectorBridge(
            CustomMoveFactory(someProperty, otherProperty),
            randomSelection
        )
    }
```

To summarize: We really need to plug our own MoveSelector with the custom factory. I think this is not possible with Optaplanner 8 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting extension.

Motivation for the changes in 8:

- the `buildBaseMoveSelector` was not public API (the `config` package was not in the `api` package, we only guaranteed XML backwards compatibility for package `config` in 7). Now, we also guarantee API backwards compatibility for package `config`, so including programmatic configuration, because we moved all `build*` methods out of it.
- In 8.2 or later we want to internalize the configuration in the SolverFactory, so we can build thousands of Solver instances faster. For example, loading classes wouldn't to be done only at SolverFactory build, once, no longer at every Solver build.

Anyway, let's first see if you can use the default way to override the moves of the CH, by explicitly configuring the `queuedEntityPlacer` and it's `MoveIteratorFactory`? https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#allocateEntityFromQueueConfiguration

I guess not, because you'd need mimic support... for the selected entity you need to generate n moves, but always the same entity during 1 placement (hence the need for mimicing).

Clearly, the changes in 8 prevent users from plugging in their own MoveSelectors (= which is an internal API, but anyway). We might be able to add an internal API to allow that again.

Comment: Chat discussion: https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232679-optaplanner/topic/Custom.20MoveSelectors